# Sending parameters to a javascript function from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works fine to send one parameter to a javascript function, but when I add a second parameter, it doesn't.  `onclick="open_livemass(\"Devotion\",'+devotion_channel.idx+');"`.  Is this the right way to send these parameters to the function?  One parameter is static.  The other, `devotion_channel.idx`, is determined by the javascript that creates the HTML.

```
show_devotion_alert = '<span style="cursor:pointer;"'+
  'onclick="open_livemass(\"Devotion\",'+devotion_channel.idx+');"><br/>'+
  devotion_name+' '+time_info+'<br/>('+devotion_channel.name+')</span>';

$('#Devotion_alert').html(show_devotion_alert);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing quote styles

```
'onclick="open_livemass(\'Devotion\',' + devotion_channel.idx + ');"
```

But why not do this:

```
show_devotion_alert = '<span id="newSP" style="cursor:pointer;"><br/>'+
  devotion_name+' '+time_info+'<br/>('+devotion_channel.name+')</span>';

$('#Devotion_alert').html(show_devotion_alert);

$("#newSP").click(function() {
    open_livemass("Devotion", devotion_channel.idx);
});
```

Or better yet:

```
show_devotion_alert = $('<span />').css("cursor", "pointer").html("<br/>" +
  devotion_name + ' ' + time_info + '<br/>(' + devotion_channel.name + ')');

show_devotion_alert.click(function() {
    open_livemass("Devotion", devotion_channel.idx);
});

$('#Devotion_alert').html(show_devotion_alert);
```

Comment: Direct event binding is _always_ better than encoding an `onclick` attribute in the HTML string.

Comment: Looks like the problem was the `,` was in the wrong place in the quotes.  Several other people had suggestions about using the click event.  That makes sense.

Comment: @user823527 - yeah - trying to insert click handlers like that is painful -- jQuery makes it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Devotion_alert').empty().append( $( "<span>", {
    css: {
        cursor: "pointer"
    },

    html: "<br />" + devotion_name + " " + time_info + "<br />",

    click: $.proxy( open_livemass, this, "Devotion", devotion_channel.idx )
}));
```

Comment: Good tip for having css, html and event neatly specified when creating new elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
show_devotion_alert = "<span style=\"cursor:pointer;\" onclick=\"open_livemass(\"Devotion\","+devotion_channel.idx+");\"><br />"+devotion_name+" "+time_info+"<br />("+devotion_channel.name+")</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try this.

```
var show_devotion_alert = '<span style="cursor:pointer;"><br />' 
                        + devotion_name + ' ' + time_info + '<br />('
                        + devotion_channel.name + ')<span/>';


$('#Devotion_alert').html(show_devotion_alert)
.find('span')
.click(function(){
    open_livemass('Devotion', devotion_channel.idx);
});
```

Comment: Looks like specifying the click separately is a good way to fix the problem.